# textarea Behavior on Chrome/Android vs Safari/iOS

Tags: html, angular, typescript, google-chrome, safari

I am working on an Angular 8 webapp project for use by multiple platforms (iOS, Android, Windows, etc.).  I have noticed there are a few differences in appearance between using Safari and Chrome.  For example, when placing an `ngIf` within a `<div>` with a false condition, it will not show up in the view on Safari when it becomes true, but does show up in Chrome (placing the `ngIf` in a `<ng-container>` wrapper fixes this problem).

My current issue regards using `<textarea>`.  When using the following `textarea` in Safari, there is a backspace issue that keeps occurring.  I am able to write the first line of text and, before the carriage return, backspace works as intended (remove the single character immediately to the left of the cursor).  After a carriage return, if a backspace is used, all the characters before the cursor are deleted, while all the characters after the cursor, if any,  remain.  This behavior occurs when the cursor is in any position on any line other than the first line, where I can still use the backspace as expected.  The first screenshot below shows what each line contains before I place the cursor at the end of the second line.  The second screenshot shows what happens once I press the backspace button.

[image: textarea before the backspace]

[image: textarea after the backspace]

This behavior is not observed when using Chrome, Firefox, or Edge, but rather behaves as expected.  I am running on a Macbook Pro Mojave with the most recent browser versions as of posting.  This behavior is occurring both locally and in production for developers and users (not limited to just my setup).

Any ideas on what is causing this behavior and how to mitigate it?

Here is the code that is being used (due to proprietary issues, I am only sharing the referenced elements/functions, not the entire files):

From Child HTML

```
<textarea class="textbox form-control hammerContainer" id="{{id}}" name="textArea" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" rows="{{rowNumbers}}"
  #textArea value="{{value}}" [attr.minLength]="minlength" [attr.maxLength]="maxlength" (keyup)="writeValue($event.target.value)"
  (blur)="onTouched()" (paste)="onPaste($event)" (click)="getCursorPos(textArea)" (keydown)="getCursorPos(textArea)" (contextmenu)="getCursorPos(textArea)"
  (select)="getCursorPos(textArea)" (press)="getCursorPos(textArea)" (tap)="getCursorPos(textArea)">
</textarea>
```

From Child .ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output [...more imports...], EventEmitter, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
```

```
@Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter<string>();
private caretPosStart: number = 0;
private caretPosEnd: number = 0;
public onChange: Function = (val: string) => { };
public onTouched: Function = () => { };
```

```
constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
```

```
public writeValue(value: any): void {
  if (value !== null && value !== undefined) {
    this.value = value.substring(0,this.maxlength);
    this.onChange(this.value);
    this.valueChange.emit(this.value);
  }
}
```

```
public getCursorPos(element: any): void {
  if (element.selectionEnd || element.selectionEnd === 0) {
    this.caretPosStart = element.selectionStart;
    this.caretPosEnd = element.selectionEnd;
  }
}
```

```
onPaste(event: ClipboardEvent): void {
  try {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default action in order to not duplicate pasted value
    const clipboardData = event ? event.clipboardData : undefined;
    let pastedText = clipboardData ? clipboardData.getData('text') : '';
    if (pastedText) {
      const selectedText = window.getSelection().toString(); // Get selected text, if any
      // If selectedText has data, then this.value should exist with data as well, hence why there is no additional checks for
      // this.value before setting currentTextArr
      if (selectedText) {
        // Split selectedText and this.value into arrays in order to compare the string values.
        // If any string values match, and based on caret position in case of multiples of same word(s), filter/remove them
        const selectedTextArr = selectedText.split(' ');
        const currentTextArr = this.value.split(' ');
        let firstMatchIndex;
        let currentStrCount = 0;
        for (let x = 0; x < currentTextArr.length; x++) {
          currentStrCount += (currentTextArr[x].length + 1);
          for (let i = 0; i < selectedTextArr.length; i++) {
            if (currentTextArr[x] === selectedTextArr[i] && ((this.caretPosStart < currentStrCount) && ((currentStrCount - 2) <= this.caretPosEnd))) {
              if (!firstMatchIndex) {
                firstMatchIndex = x; // setting index based on the first word match to know where to insert pasted text
              }
              currentTextArr.splice(x, 1);
            }
          }
        }
        // If there was a match, insert the pasted text based on the index of the first matched word, otherwise the pasted text will be placed at the end
        // of the current data. Then format the array back into a string and write the value.
        let finalText;
        if (firstMatchIndex) {
          currentTextArr.splice(firstMatchIndex, 0, pastedText);
          finalText = currentTextArr.join(' ');
        } else {
          finalText = currentTextArr.join(' ') + ' ' + pastedText;
        }
        this.writeValue(finalText);
        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        // Update caret position after paste
        this.caretPosStart = finalText.length;
        this.caretPosEnd = finalText.length;
      } else {
        // Check to see if there is existing data
        if (this.value) {
          // If the carotPos is less than the current strings length, add the
          // pasted text where the cursor is
          if (this.caretPosStart < this.value.length) {
            pastedText = this.value.slice(0, this.caretPosStart) + pastedText + this.value.slice(this.caretPosStart);
          } else { // Otherwise add pasted text after current data
            pastedText = this.value + ' ' + pastedText;
          }
        }
        this.writeValue(pastedText);
        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        // Update caret position after paste
        this.caretPosStart = pastedText.length;
        this.caretPosEnd = pastedText.length;
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // Do nothing if error occurs. This just prevents the app from breaking if there is an issue handling the pasting of data.
    // However, will still be able to enter additional narrative text manually.
  }
}
```

From Parent HTML

```
<app-textarea (valueChange)='setSpecialInstructions($event)'>
</app-textarea>
```

From Parent .ts

```
setSpecialInstructions(value: string) {
  this.specialInstructions = value;
  this.someService.setSpecialInstructions(this.specialInstructions);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I forgot to add was the CSS file for the child component that contained the `<textarea>` tag.  The hammerContainer class was as follows:

```
.hammerContainer {
  user-select: all !important;
}
```

`user-select` is a CSS style that I've never encountered before (this code was written by someone else).  After some research, I found that the appropriate style to use when controlling that setting in Safari is `-webkit-user-select` like so:

```
.hammer-container {
  user-select: all !important;
  -webkit-user-select: text !important;
}
```

While `user-select` uses the `all` setting, this setting is not supported by Safari, thus the need for the `text` setting in `-webkit-user-select`.  The `!important` ensures the default value of `none` is overridden.